# Conditional Left Join TableA with Attribute.TableB based on value from Max(AllocDate.TableB) below ProdDate.TableA SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, conditional-statements, max

I have TableA where each cow's milk production is recorded on a weekly basis

| ProdDate | CowID | Prod |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15/11/2021 | 1501 | 30 |
| 8/11/2021 | 1501 | 28 |
| 1/11/2021 | 1501 | 26 |
| 25/10/2021 | 1501 | 27 |
| 15/11/2021 | 1716 | 25 |
| 8/11/2021 | 1716 | 25 |
| 1/11/2021 | 1716 | 27 |
| 25/10/2021 | 1716 | 28 |

And TableB is where each cow gets allocated a Feed Ration from time to time (Once a month)

| AllocDate | CowID | RationGroup |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/10/2021 | 1501 | Red |
| 1/11/2021 | 1501 | Blue |
| 1/10/2021 | 1716 | Red |
| 1/11/2021 | 1716 | Yellow |

I need to determine what each cow's RationGroup was at the time each production point was recorded in TableA such that the below is produced.

| ProdDate | CowID | Prod | FeedGroup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15/11/2021 | 1501 | 30 | Blue |
| 8/11/2021 | 1501 | 28 | Blue |
| 1/11/2021 | 1501 | 26 | Blue |
| 25/10/2021 | 1501 | 27 | Red |
| 15/11/2021 | 1716 | 25 | Yellow |
| 8/11/2021 | 1716 | 25 | Yellow |
| 1/11/2021 | 1716 | 27 | Yellow |
| 25/10/2021 | 1716 | 28 | Red |

How could this be achieved in SQL Server?
The logic I am struggling with is to Left Join TableA with FeedGroup.TableB based on value from Max(AllocDate.TableB) below ProdDate.TableA. What would this code look like in SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` here to select the appropriate matching row:

```
select a.*, p.RationGroup
from a
outer apply (
    select top (1) RationGroup
    from b
    where b.cowid=a.cowid and a.proddate>=b.allocDate
    order by b.AllocDate desc
)p
```